# Modify SQL column field to be nullable, if I added constraint do I need to remove constraint as well?

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, constraints, alter

I altered a table with the following script

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ADD [flagField] CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ADD CONSTRAINT XCK6_tablename CHECK([flagField] in ('Y', 'N'));
```

If I want to reverse this script to change that field in the table to allow a nullable state, do I need to remove the constraint before making the field nullable?

so if I run

```
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ALTER COLUMN fieldFlag CHAR(1) NULL
```

will that be fine as is or should I also remove the constraint?

Comment: Are you using MySQL 8+?  If not, check constraints won't even work.

Comment: The check should not need to be (permanently) removed. However, it will still prevent NULL from being inserted unless it is updated to allow such.

Comment: ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ALTER [flagField] CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE TABLENAME ALTER CONSTRAINT XCK6_tablename CHECK([flagField] in ('Y', 'N',null));

Comment: @dxlachx . . . Your syntax looks like SQL Server, not MySQL.  Although that doesn't affect the answer (in this case), you should correctly tag your questions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff you're right my apologies -- fixed

Answer (score 1):

You only have to make the field `NULL`able.

The logic for constraints differs from the logic for `WHERE` and `CASE WHEN` conditions.  For `WHERE` and `CASE WHEN`, `NULL` results are treated the same as false.

`CHECK` is instead validating the data.  It accepts as valid anything that is not *explicitly* false.  So, there is no need to include `NULL` checking in the constraint.

If you did, the correct logic would be:

```
CHECK (flagField in ('Y', 'N') or flagField is null)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0debb34b88f51b0b0fac0cf347b2c642) is a db<>fiddle illustrating that the behavior is as described above.